# FlashBuilder 4.5 + PHP + mssql list output

Tags: php, sql-server, apache-flex, flash-builder, flash-builder4.5

I've created a web service with the following code:

```
class WebUser {
    public $USERID;
}

class UseridService
{
    public $username = "my_user";
    public $password = "my_pw";
    public $server = "my_remote_server";
    public $databasename = "my_database";
    public $tablename = "my_table";

    function __construct ()
    {
        $this->con = mssql_connect($this->server, $this->username, $this->password) or die('Connection failed!');
        mssql_select_db($this->databasename);
    }

    public function getUserid ()
    {
        $sql = "Select top 10 USERID FROM my_table";
        $result = mssql_query($sql);
        $rows = array();
        while ($row = mssql_fetch_assoc($result))
        {
            $storage = new WebUser();
            $storage->USERID = $row['USERID'];
            $rows[] = $row;
        }
        mssql_close($this->con);
        return $rows;
    }
}
```

For now in flash builder 4.5, I want to output the top 10 userids into a List component in my canvas. I can assure everyone that the PHP webservice code I wrote works and returns an array of WebUser() objects with just the USERID string inside.

There is a lot of documentation online for MySQL and how they simply "drag and drop" the webservice into a list and it "magically" works. Despite trying to follow their conventions using MSSQL instead, I simply cannot get it working.

I was hoping if anyone can offer a piece of advice on what to do? Even if it's not an answer itself, does anyone know any online documentation that works specifically with Flashbuilder/PHP/MSSQL?

Comment: maybe this will help: http://corlan.org/2008/10/10/flex-and-php-remoting-with-amfphp/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to the source! Adobe Documentation on setting this up:

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash-builder/articles/flashbuilder-php-part1.html

They walk you through hooking up a service in Flashbuilder, connecting your data objects, and displaying them.

I know what you're asking asks for MSSQL, but the database you use on the back-end doesn't matter. **What matters is serializing your object from the server-side to the client-side (i.e. PHP to AS3)** which means matching the objects on both ends or finding a way to convert them (i.e. JSON-encoded objects in a REST-based web service can be de-serialized quite smoothly using the as3core library as an example).

Comment: Thanks for the link! I took some time and did some additional research with the power of Google and your link. Turned out I had a flawed understanding of how webservices worked with frontend frameworks, but now I know which direction to go.

Comment: Awesome! It took me a while to understand too. Just think of the "client" level as everything on the front-end / presentational, and the "service" layer handling all the business logic.